# ng-repeat with filter based upon $scope list

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is regarding AngularJS.

I've got 2 lists in my $scope:

```
$scope.cars = [{ name: 'Audi', price: '...' }, { name: 'BMW', price: '...' }];
$scope.favorites = ['Audi'];
```

I'm generating a "Add to favourite" list in HTML with:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="car in cars"><button ng-click="addToFav($index)">Add to favourite</button></li>
</ul>
```

But I would like to not have the "Add to" button on cars which already exists in my favourite list.

Is that possible with:

```
... | filter {}
```

in the ng-repeat statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create filter:

```
angular.module('app').filter('isNotInArray', function () {
    return function (arr, targetArr, prop) {
        return arr.filter(function (item) {
            return targetArr.indexOf(item[prop]) === -1;
        });
    };
});
```

Then use:

```
<li ng-repeat="car in cars | isNotInArray:favorites:'name'">
```

Comment: Wow, thanks. What if targetArr isn't just ['Audi', '...'] but [{name: 'Audi', ...},{name: '...', ...}]?

Comment: Then you write: `return !targetArr.some(function (targetItem) { return targetItem[prop] === item[prop]; });` instead of `return targetArr.indexOf(item[prop]) === -1;`

Answer (score 0):

You can also add a new key in your cars list and check usgin ng-if condition

```
    $scope.cars = [{ name: 'Audi', price: '...', isFav:true }, { name: 'BMW', price: '...', isFav:false }];

    $scope.favorites = ['Audi'];
```